# C++ ifstream Error Checking

Tags: c++, error-handling, ifstream

I am new to C++ and want to add error checking to my code plus I want to make sure I'm using good coding practices.  I read a line from an ASCII file into a string using:

```
ifstream paramFile;
string tmp;

//open input file

tmp.clear();

paramFile >> tmp;

//parse tmp
```

1. How can I error check to make sure the input file read was successful?
2. I'm seeing much more complicated ways of reading from an ASCII file out there.  Is the way I'm doing it "safe/robust"?

Comment: `std::string`'s default constructor makes an empty string. No need for the `clear()`. Also, if you want a line, use `std::getline`.

Comment: Thanks for the link lightness

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`paramFile >> tmp;` If the line contains spaces, this will not read the whole line. If you want that use `std::getline(paramFile, tmp);` which reads up until the newline. Basic error checking is done by examining the return values. For example:

```
if(paramFile>>tmp) // or if(std::getline(paramFile, tmp))
{
    std::cout << "Successful!";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "fail";
}
```

`operator>>` and `std::getline` both return a reference to the stream. The stream evaluates to a boolean value which you can check after the read operation. The above example will only evaluate to true if the read was successful.

Here is an example of how I might make your code:

```
ifstream paramFile("somefile.txt"); // Use the constructor rather than `open`
if (paramFile) // Verify that the file was open successfully
{
    string tmp; // Construct a string to hold the line
    while(std::getline(paramFile, tmp)) // Read file line by line
    {
         // Read was successful so do something with the line
    }
}
else
{
     cerr << "File could not be opened!\n"; // Report error
     cerr << "Error code: " << strerror(errno); // Get some info as to why
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I didn't know you could evaluate a stream as boolean.  Very helpful!

Comment: Yes, all streams have this, as they inherit it from `std::basic_ios`. Here is a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: Great reference Jesse!  I hadn't found that one yet.  Thanks!

Comment: HAY! you don't check for IO errors whe file already open(!) how to do that correctly ?

Comment: @socketpair: Could you explain more? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Suppose file is already open (successfully). Next, I read some data successfuly. But unfortunatelly someone removes floppy drive with my file. I'mt trying to read and receive IOerror from OS syscall. So, How I can detect such situation? In other words, We should distinguish between EOF and IOError.

std::getline returns stream. operator bool on the stream returns "!stream->fail()". but on eof failbit is also set... so logic become nightmare. (see table at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail) and also, note that trying to read stream which is at EOF also set failbit. AAAAAAA :(

Comment: @socketpair: `I'm trying to read and receive IOerror from OS syscall.`. That's what `errno` is for, I use it on the last line `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: @socketpair: io error is indicated by `badbit`. So you can check for `stream->bad()` for this matter, I believe. This should tell that the problem is in i/o, but still without any details. `errno` should work but there's no guarantee that it will be set or it worn't be corrupted by the stream itself.